# Transfer image files from MongoDB to S3

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, gridfs, s3cmd

I have a NodeJS app that stores all of its data, even images, to MongoDB. Now I want to use an S3 to store my app's files (images, 43gb) and so, I need to transfer there all files that I have in my mongo.

I found the `s3cmd` tool that can transfer my files to the S3 instance (DigitalOcean space), but I can't find a way to actually access those files. I know they are stored in the `fs.files` and `fs.chunks` collections, but I can't figure out how to actually use them as input to `s3cmd`!

Any help will be much appreciated!!!

> EDIT: This is the format the images are being stored with:

**fs.files**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ae97922c1dabec8d2d0bdb0"),
  "filename" : "2b57455f3878d11dabc9c984da7de314_postImage.jpeg",
  "contentType" : "binary/octet-stream",
  "length" : 2291623,
  "chunkSize" : 261120,
  "uploadDate" : ISODate("2018-05-02T08:38:58.549Z"),
  "aliases" : null,
  "metadata" : null,
  "md5" : "9ad420eaa7c28a73e449199430627802"
}
```

**fs.chunks.findOne()**

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ae2d77f6616b4a9d93cb4b1"),
  "files_id" : ObjectId("5ae2d77f6616b4a9d93cb4b0"),
  "n" : 0,
  "data" : BinData(0,"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAuAAAAJvCAYAAAA6OGQEAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAABWWlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIgeDp4bXB0az0iWE1QIENvcmUgNS40LjAiPgogICA8cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRher38tcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=") }
```

Comment: Are you trying to move the binary blobs you've stored in MongoDB to S3, or the actual files on disk that make up the MongoDB database (ie the files contained in \data\db by default)?  You can literally copy the data directory from one MongoDB installation to another. So simply uploading the files would be sufficient.  Perhaps I misunderstand your question.

Comment: All I want is to get the images from my mongo and transfer them to the S3. I know that images in mongo are stored in chunks, so I guess the binary blobs?

Comment: Unless there is some feature of S3 that allows it to reach out to your MongoDB and pull byte arrays, I think you will have to do this programmatically. I'm not aware of any method to have a MongoDB server push documents to a non-mongoDB target.

Comment: Ok! Programmatically then! Do you have any idea how?

Comment: I imagine you'd use the NodeJS driver to pull your data and push it to S3 via the S3 SDK https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/

Comment: And you think it's feasible for the size of my data? (43gb)

Answer (score 0):

So, basically what you can do, it's to create a [Writable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams) where you have to access the DB to read all the documents, and inside of the write method you're going to upload the file to AWS S3 and probably later update the mongodb document with the returned information.

An example could be:

```js
// uploadFile.js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const BUCKET_NAME = 'my-bucket';
const S3 = new AWS.S3();

// This function will upload the file to AWS S3 in the defined bucket 
const uploadFile = (Body, Key, opts = {}) =>
 S3.upload(
      {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key,
        Body,
        ...opts
      }
  ).promise();
```

```js
// migrate.js

const client = require("../mongo-client");
const { Writable, pipeline } = require("stream");
const util = require("util");


const pipe = util.promisify(pipeline);

// this will get all the documents that are going to be migrated
const getDocuments = () =>
  client.withCollection("chunks").then(({ collection }) =>
    collection
      .find({});

// this method will update the document after the file has been uploaded to AWS S3 with
// the s3 path and version 
const updateDocument = ({ _id }) => (response) => client.withCollection("chunks")
  .then(collection => collection.update({ _id }, {$set: {awsPath: response}, $unset: ["file"] }));

// This is the writable that's going to upload and later update the document in the db
class TransferWritable extends Writable {
  _write(doc, encoding, callback) {
     uploadFile(doc._id, doc.data.buffer)
       .then(updateDocument(doc))
       .then(callback)
       .catch(callback);
  }
}


const migrate = getDocuments
  .then(stream => pipe(stream, new TransferWritable({ objectMode: true })))
  .catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this in 2 steps : Have a look [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

1. Exports the data(document-wise/collection-wise/completeDB) from mongodb.

> mongoexport --host [localhost] --db [db-name] --collection
>   [collection-name] --out [output-file.json]

2. Import the exported data to mongodb on server.

> mongoimport --host [s3-server-host] --db [db-name] --collection
>   [Collection-name] --file [input-file.json]

[DO VOTE TO THIS ANSWER, IF ITS HELPFUL TO YOU]

Comment: But that will export a collection of my db. What I want, is to export my db's files and store them to an S3 (object storage)

Comment: Then below links can be helpfull to you.
1. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/547759/Automating-backup-for-MongoDB-using-CRON-and-S3CMD

2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-scheduled-logical-mongodb-backups-to-digitalocean-spaces

Comment: I'm not having a problem on how to export a collection, neither on how to send it to S3. What I'm having trouble with is to how to export the actual files.